# Rspec fail when running the whole spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I write rspec and run line by line with line number.
It works fine and pass.

When I run the whole rspec, it fail

```
      context "scope" do
          before do
            @current_user = User.current = User.first
          end

          it "should have user" do
            @current_user.should_not be_nil
          end
      end
```

I have spending hours to find out why it is failing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure your tests are interferring.

Use databasecleaner to reset everything automatically between each test.

See ref here:

https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner